# How do you clean up an ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-arrayadapter

I am getting an out-of-memory condition when I use an array adapter and change screen orientation.  I have made the smallest fully working code that exhibits this problem.

```
package com.foobar.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class TestAppActivity extends Activity {
    protected ArrayList<ListItem> mModel = new ArrayList<ListItem>();
    protected ListAdapter mAdapter = null;
    private static Context mApplicationContext = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        System.gc();
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        if (mApplicationContext == null) { mApplicationContext = getApplicationContext(); }

        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListList);
        lv.setItemsCanFocus(true);
        mAdapter = new ListAdapter(mApplicationContext, lv, mModel);
        lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Log.i("test", "@@ start");
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        boolean change = true;
                        Thread.sleep(4 * 1000);
                        for (int ii = 0; ii < 200; ii++) {
                            setRequestedOrientation(change ? ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE : ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                            Thread.sleep(4 * 1000);
                            change = !change;
                            Log.i("test", "@@ change: " + (ii+1));
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        Log.i("test", "@@ complete!");
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

// doesn't make any difference.
//        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListList);
//        lv.setAdapter(null);
//        adapter.clear();
//        adapter = null;

        unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.ListList));
        System.gc();
    }

    private void unbindDrawables(View view) {
        if (view == null) { return; }
        if (view.getBackground() != null) { view.getBackground().setCallback(null); }

        if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
            for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) { unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i)); }
            if (!(view instanceof AdapterView)) { ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews(); }
        }
    }

    public static class ListItem {
        public int placeholder;
    }

    public static class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListItem> implements View.OnClickListener {
        public ListAdapter(Context context, ListView lv, List<ListItem> model) {
            super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, model);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { }
    }
}
```

After about 70 or so orientation changes, i get an out of memory error (because i have a particularly large background image).  My XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:dividerHeight="3dp"
        android:overScrollFooter="@null" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And my simple background looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
</LinearLayout>
```

This has been driving me crazy, because this is incredibly simple and it seems like this should work;  Is this a bug in the adapter code?

tia.

---

I have even greater simplified my code to be just this:

```
package com.foobar.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class TestAppActivity extends Activity {
    protected ArrayList<ListItem> mModel = new ArrayList<ListItem>();
    protected ListAdapter mAdapter = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListList);
        lv.setItemsCanFocus(true);
        mAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, lv, mModel);
        lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        View root = findViewById(R.id.RootView);
        ((BitmapDrawable) root.getBackground()).getBitmap().recycle();

        // this doesn't seem to have any affect.
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListList);
        lv.setAdapter(null);
        mAdapter.clear();
        mAdapter = null;

        unbindDrawables(root);
        System.gc();
    }

    private void unbindDrawables(View view) {
        if (view == null) { return; }
        if (view.getBackground() != null) { view.getBackground().setCallback(null); }

        if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
            for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) { unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i)); }
            if (!(view instanceof AdapterView)) { ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews(); }
        }
    }

}
```

If I run that code, then manually change screen orientation 20 times, then look in Eclipse Memory Analyzer Tool, it shows 20 instances of my activity.

The interesting thing is that if I do this on a 3.x device, I don't have this issue - I'm guessing this is something that was fixed in Honeycomb?

Comment: How large is the dataset in the adapter? Also, if you can why not handle the orientation change yourself, instead of allowing android to restart your activity when the screen rotates.

Comment: the data set is empty!  I guess I could handle the orientation change myself, but this is a scaled down version of a much bigger code base; where it would be much more painful to do that. :-)

Comment: turns out, that doesn't work anyway.  the underlying problem is that the lv.setAdapter(mAdapter); call would still need to be made in an orientation change whether I handle it myself or let android handle the orientation change - and that's what is somehow holding on to the activity (and very large background bitmap).

Comment: Out of curiosity, any reason for making `mApplicationContext` static? Can you try getting rid of that `mApplicationContext` variable and just using `getApplicationContext()` wherever you need it?

Comment: no good reason - just random hacking and trying things.

Comment: @user645402 After you removed it, are you still running into issues on screen orientation changes?

Comment: it doesn't matter if i have that or just call getApplicationContext() - same result.

Comment: Here's something strange.  I wound up trying the sample applications in C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\samples\android-10\ApiDemos, ran that, went to Views -> Lists -> 10. Single choice list, changed screen orientation 12 times or so, and then I ran eclipse MAT and saw 12 references to that activity that were not released!!!

Comment: Argh!!!  Answers here!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910473/i-have-a-memory-leak-using-listactivity-in-android/6530551#6530551

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997993/memory-lead-when-using-listview-in-android